# Parse file into u32strings using pugixml

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, xml-parsing, pugixml

I am trying to store the parsed information in std::u32strings.
I see from [the documentation](https://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/dom.html#manual.dom.unicode) that unicode is supported, but they only talk about wchars and wstrings.

Is there a way to use u32strings instead without explicitly having to convert it after parsing?